# Invalidating sessions in Mobile App

Tags: android, ios, session

android application which communicates with my backed server. Users have to log in to the system, and users can log out from the system any time. Every thing is working fine for me... my problem is when users press the log-out button how can i invalidate sessions.. because now when the users tries to log-out from the system using both iOS and android their session is still valid in server.

Appreciate your help

Comment: what kind of system ? web-based ?

Comment: My android application comunicates with the back end web services..

Comment: the login session is stored in web browser via cookie ? just invalidate the cookie after you logout !

Comment: My android application is not a web application, so still i need to invalidate the cookie inside my android app?

Comment: Or do i need to invalidate the seesion in Server side

Comment: Of course both side has to be invalidated

Comment: and i want to ask is this same for iOS also? do i need to invalidate the cookies in ios also?

Comment: yes during logout invalidate the session in server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ios . during logout  Invalidate session in server . if it is mobile website in ios you can use similar to delete cookies by using the following code

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
    NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
    NSArray *cookieJar = [storage cookies];
    NSLog(@"value%@",cookieJar);

    for (cookie in [storage cookies])
    {
        NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
        NSLog(@"value%@",domainName);
        NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
        if(domainRange.length > 0)
        {
            [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
        }
    }
```